# How do I remove a full file?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

Some 32 bit (mostly lib) files were downloaded to my computer by mistake.  How do I find them all and delete them with their contents?

Comment: It depends, by what means were they downloaded?

Comment: Which command or application have you used to do that `apt-get`, software center,...?

Comment: Please consider to upvote all answers which you found helpful and mark the best of them as "accepted answer"

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name you can use

```
sudo apt-get remove *packagename*
```

to uninstall. **but make sure that they don't have any dependencies.**

or use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

From the man page:

> autoremove (and the auto-remove alias since 1.1)
>              autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and
>   are now no longer needed.

or use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

From the man page:

> clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/ and
>              /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.

or:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

From the man page:

> autoclean (and the auto-clean alias since 1.1)
>              Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes
>   package files that can no longer
>              be downloaded, and are largely useless. This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of control.
>   The configuration option
>              APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being erased if it is set to off.

please read the manual page of apt-get

```
man apt-get
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you downloaded them "by hand", and not via `apt-get`, open a console and type:

```
cd 
find . -name "FileName"
```

`cd` will go to your home-directory

`find` will search `.` (the current directory) for a file with the given name. If you dont know the full filename, you can use e.g. `*File*`. That would list all files which have `File` somewhere in the name.

(probably on Ubuntu there is as well a graphical way to search)